# How to get a click-able link for a shared file, when sending an e-mail with the file-name in it

Tags: email, samba, file-sharing, url

I've got a local network with a shared drive mounted to it, all machines running Fedora (and some Windows).

When we want to share a file, there is no easy way of just getting a link for the file like in windows, but rather I need to get the directory first, and then append the filename at the end i.e
[smb://server/share/files/Documentation.odt](http://google.com)

That in itself is cumbersome, but the problem occurs when a filename has spaces in it, then the link that is sent by e-mail is rendered totally useless and looks something like this:

[smb://server/share/files/Set](http://google.com) Up Documentation.odt

Is there anything that I could do in order to have a simple maybe right-click solution which gives me the link of the file to send in an e-mail (preferably a non-terminal solution).

Comment: What do you use to send the email?

Comment: Spaces in URLs can be encoded; so a file name `20% better` would end up as `smb://server/path/20%25%20better`. (The ASCII code for the percent sign is 0x25 and space is 0x20.)

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, problem solved.
All I had to do was `CTRL+C` on the file itself, and then paste it into the e-mail.

Silly question